# Publish Firefox extensions automatically

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

Is it possible to publish Firefox extensions hosted by Mozilla automatically through the API (like through the [Google Web Store API](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/using_webstore_api))?

I can not find any documentation about this. I want to publish my extensions automatically using Bitbucket Pipelines and the only option I see at the moment is to host my extensions by myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm quite sure you can use npm to fetch 'web-ext', the command line tool that is able to upload new versions to addons.mozilla.org.

Have a look at the documentation:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Getting_started_with_web-ext